# ractive.js Cannot assign to read only property 'innerHTML'?

Tags: javascript, html, drupal, ractivejs

I've run and tested my ractive script on a basic html site and it worked just fine but when I try adding it to an existing page it fails to render anything to the screen. Does anyone know of environmental issues that might cause this error : Cannot assign to read only property 'innerHTML'?  I've checked the basics like making sure all my scripts are loaded etc. I'm wondering if someone has ran into a similar issue or might be able suggest things to test next as I don't have much to go on.

I've made my script available as a gist: [here](https://gist.github.com/nwpointer/9d0e623efda97878979f)

Comment: Not really sure what it's supposed to do, but here is http://jsfiddle.net/4px7d8zs/ with that gist running and it changes to "programFavoritesList" when you re-run.

Comment: It sounds very weird - never encountered anything like it, and [google suggests](https://www.google.com/search?q=Cannot+assign+to+read+only+property+%27innerHTML%27%3F&oq=Cannot+assign+to+read+only+property+%27innerHTML%27%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=Cannot+assign+to+read+only+property+%27innerHTML%27) it's not an error that anyone else has had, with or without Ractive. Has someone done something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/ae03nw6u/)? You could try rendering to a different element to see what happens